# Return HTTP 204 with just Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I have an app that uses lighttpd to log requests to a pixel, but the client doesn't need any response. Currently the requests map to a small static image. Is there a way to configure lighttpd to respond to these requests with a 204 header without using any fcgi/etc handler? I.e. done purely by the lighty server itself?

Comment: What a useful question, Andy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lighttpd doesn't seem to have an option to do this, so the only way would be to write a [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) script using [mod_magnet](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModMagnet). The script shouldn't require more than this:

```
return 204
```

And the corresponding configuration:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_magnet" )
$HTTP["url"] == "/somepath" {
    magnet.attract-raw-url-to = ( "/etc/lighttpd/204.lua" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using: setenv.add-response-header = ()? (This requires "mod_setenv")

Comment: The response code is part of the http response's status line, not the headers, so I don't think setenv does the trick

Comment: You are completely right:) Sorry